# Sorting fetched data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I retrieving data from firebase I tried to sort by price to descending order. but its not working. I tried the below query.

```
func sortPriceMaxtoMin(){
    db.collection("Ads").order(by: "price", descending: true).getDocuments(){ (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error getting documents")
        }
        else{
            self.ads1 = QuerySnapshot!.documents.map({ queryDocumentSnapshot in
                 let val = try! queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Ad.self)
                print("id is : \(val.id)=> title: \(val.title)")

                return AdsData(title: val.title, seller: val.seller, image: val.image, price: val.price
                               , district: val.district,address: val.address, landSize: val.landSize)
            }
        )}
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to SwiftUI (which is a UI framework) at all -- this is just Swift

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know query for sorting this. app is working fine. now I just wanted to sort by price descending order

Comment: If you change the code to `print("id is : \(val.id)=> title: \(val.price)")`, what is the output?

Comment: I just checked the id and one field if it is retrieving fine or not. it's working fine

Comment: So is the output shown in the console sorted by price, descending order?